# Trying to compile Maven project using Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, build, compilation

I am trying to compile Maven project in Eclipse. The project is an open-source point-of-sale software called FloreantPOS. In their forum a read some tutorial from a guy who compiled the source code with Eclipse. The steps:

1) Run Eclipse, then File > Import > Existing Maven Project

2) Root directory > Browse the folder with the source code

3) Click Finish, project is opened

4) Right click on project > Maven > Update Project

5) Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Remove JRE Libraries

6) Project > Properties > Java Build Path > RE-Add JRE Libraries (lastest 
ver installed (JDK 1.8.0_71)) > Apply > OK

7) Project > Clean

After cleaning the project i have 50 warning, but most of them are (method is never locally used) or (method is never used). Just one of the warnings is different, saying (The method connection() from the type Session is deprecated). So the project should be OK for building, right ? Well, when I right click project > Build Project, nothing happens. I can run the project via right click > run as > java application and it runs fine, so im confused. What i do wrong? Can someone help me, please? Thank you!

Comment: From what you describe it seems that the project is compiling ok. Though I am not sure what you expect after building it. Do you want the generated artifact (jar/war)? Do you want to execute the application?

Comment: If you want a jar as output be sure that the packaging tag in Pom.xml is setter to jar

Comment: Then where is the compiled program located (program.jar)? There are no "bin" folder in the project dir or anything. I am kinda noob in Java and this Eclipse, i might be just no understanding how they work.

Edit: pom.xml is set to: Packaging: jar

Answer (score 0):

**maven**'s results of a build (resources, classes, jar/war files, reports or, in general, any result of the compilation) are located in **target** directory. [Maven Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

```
- project-dir
  | pom.xml
  + src
  + target
    | classes
    | <your-project.name>-<version>.jar
    | ...
```

To run that file, just need to execute:

```
java -jar <your-project.name>-<version>.jar
```

Comment: But the output .jar is not generated anywhere in the project directory. I tried Build Project, Build All, Run As Java Application and just the output .JAR file doesn't get generated. Searched the project directory 1000's of times. In the target/classes dir i have all the other files required to run the program, but no the actual .jar file.

Comment: Btw, when i click on "Console" i see : 

Adding plugins in 'raw' classpaths, such as 'bin/' or 'classes/' is not recommended. Please use classpath://* instead (the video is a bit outdated in this respect).

Written with red letters. Could this be the problem ?